# How to match a number but not a string and number together?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a variable like this

```
p <= 0;
p <= q0;
```

I want to get only the line `p <= q0` but not `p <= 0` so I used the code below to get the the thing except number but it cannot get the q0 also since behind q there is a  number.

```
if ($string2 =~ m/^(.*)(<=)(.*)(;)/g) {
     unless ($3 =~ /[0-9]/) {
        push @des, $1;
        push @source, $3;
     }
}
```

This is part of the code to match these two lines. $string 2 is first p<=0 and follow by p<=q0.

Comment: Did you mean to say that you have strings like that? `"p <= 0"` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way with regex would be to check if `$3` does NOT match any letters....

```
if ( $3 !~ /[A-z]/) { ... }
```

If you just want to check if `$3` looks like a number, then use `looks_like_number`... It's in the core.

```
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';

# Later...

if ( $string2 =~ m/^(.*)(<=)(.*)(;)/g ) {
    if ( looks_like_number($3) ) {
        push @des, $1;
        push @source, $3;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Forgot to point out that once you do another regex match, you lose the temporary capture variables (eg, `$1`, `$2`, etc).

Use named captures to get around this. Also, I suspect that you do not need to capture the `<=` and the `;`. If that is the case, then you do not need to wrap them in brackets.

```
if ( $string2 =~ m/^(?<des>.*) <= (?<source>.*);/ ) {
    if ( $+{source} !~ /[A-z]/) {
        push @des, $+{des};
        push @source, $+{source};
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank. It success to enter the unless statement by using if ( $3 !~ /[A-z]/) but I cannot get anything into @ des and @ source. Anything wrong to my code?

Comment: @tim yes, it is. After the 2d comparison yours initial $1 and $3 aren't available any more, you need to save them in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
if($string2=~m/^([a-z,0-9]+)\s*(<=)\s*([a-z,0-9]+)(;)/g){
     my $d=$1;   
     my $s=$3;
     if ($3 =~ /[a-z]/){  
        push @des, $d;
        push @source, $s;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do it with just one match, depending on exactly what you want. If you want to match where the right-hand side is an identifier starting with a letter, this would work:

```
if ($string2 =~ m/^(.*)<=\s*([a-z]\w*)\s*;/gi) {
    push @des, $1;
    push @source, $2;
}
```